# How to cancel a superclasses' overriding of a default Matlab function

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, a superclass and subclass. The subclass inherits from the superclass.

The superclass redefines the default Matlab function `disp()`. However, I want the subclass to "cancel" this redefinition and go back to using the default Matlab version of `disp()`. Is there any way to do this?

I know that subclasses can call superclasses' methods via the following syntax

```
function result = CallTheSuperClassMethod(obj, arg1, arg2)
  result = TheSuperClassMethod@TheSuperClass(obj, arg1, arg2)
end
```

But is there a way to call the Matlab default method via something like:

```
function result = CallTheDefaultMethod(obj, arg1, arg2)
  result = SomeMethod@DefaultClass(obj, arg1, arg2)
end
```

where I am assuming that `DefaultClass` is the class from which all Matlab classes inherit.

Here's a concrete example. I have two classes, defined as follows:

```
classdef blah_super
  properties
    superprop = 'super property';
  end

  methods
    function disp(obj)
      disp('super');
    end
  end
end

classdef blah_sub < blah_super
  properties
    subprop = 'sub property';
  end
end
```

Here are the results of a few commands that I get:

```
>> a = blah_super

a = 

super

>> b = blah_sub

b = 

super
```

But I want to modify `blah_sub` somehow (while still inheriting from `blah_super`) so the result is:

```
>> b = blah_sub

b = 

  blah_sub with properties:

      subprop: 'sub property'
    superprop: 'super property'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`builtin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html)

So the definition of `blah_sub` would be something like this:

```
classdef blah_sub < blah_super
  properties
    subprop = 'sub property';
  end

  methods
    function disp(obj)
      builtin('disp', obj);
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This relatively obscure function never turned up in my web searches, which focused on Matlab's OOP documentation.